# How to control the kafka connection retries in Reactor Kafka/Reactive Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, project-reactor, reactor-kafka

I am using **Reactor-Kafka** in spring boot application. I am trying to handle the transient errors where If kafka goes down then I want to keep retrying to connect to kafka indefinitely.

I have observed the default behavior which is, reactive kafka consumes the batch, then process each record and auto commit the entire batch. Now, if in beetween the batch, kafka connection is lost then **by default** it tries to **reconnect** for **100 times** within approx 10 seconds. So, how to modify this behavior?

I have already tried with setting up the following properties:

```
reconnect.backoff.ms: 2000ms
reconnect.backoff.max.ms: 5000ms
```

Also tried following properties:

```
akka.kafka.consumer.reconnection-max-retries: 300
akka.kafka.consumer.reconnection-min-backoff: 1000ms
akka.kafka.consumer.reconnection-max-backoff: 5m
akka.kafka.consumer.reconnection-random-factor: 0.5
```

But none of the properties are working and I am not able to increase / decrease the 100 retries.

> Note: I am also using Kafka Autoconfigure for the configurations.

How to achieve that?

**Question Update**

**1.**
The way I am using Autoconfiguration is with **KafkaProperties class**:

```
@Bean
public ReceiverOptions<String, String> receiverOptions(KafkaProperties kafkaProperties) {

    return ReceiverOptions
          .<String, String>create(kafkaProperties.buildConsumerProperties())
          .subscription(Collections.singleton("topic-name"));

}
```

Where KafkaProperties will automatically read the configurations from application.properties/application.yml

**2.** When kafka tries to reconnect, it does for 100 times and then stops consuming it. So, how to control that number also?

Answer (score 0):

Akka has nothing to do with Reactor Kafka and Spring Boot. So, definitely those `akka.kafka.consumer` won't be applied to your Reactor Kafka consumer.

On the other hand there is no Reactor Kafka auto-configuration in Spring Boot yet: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/pull/30567. So, again that info is not relevant and something whatever you'd like to configure in the `application.properties` won't be picked up automatically by the `ReceiverOptions` for the `KafkaReceiver` in REactor Kafka. You may play with the `ReceiverOptions`  options population manually, for example you can definitely set that `reconnect.backoff.ms` into `static <K, V> ReceiverOptions<K, V> create(@NonNull Map<String, Object> configProperties) {`.

You also may pay attention to the `maxCommitAttempts` and `commitRetryInterval` properties of the `ReceiverOptions`.

Comment: I have updated the question with respect to auto configuration. and provided more details @ArtemBilan.

Comment: I think that `100` is definitely about that `maxCommitAttempts` of the `ReceiverOptions`.

Comment: Yes, when I have printed the maxCommitAttempts values it is 100. But If I am changing it, it is not getting applied. I have tried like this `receiverOptions.maxCommitAttempts(30);` And also tried changing the commitRetryInterval, but that also is not working, ex: `receiverOptions.commitRetryInterval(Duration.ofSeconds(2L));`